# wymeditor get value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea, wymeditor

I want to send the value of the wymeditor field with ajax.
The code is like below;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "forms.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    data: {action: 'add', parent: $('input.parent').val(), ntag: $('input.tag').val(), description: $('.wymeditor').html()},
});
```

I tried for the value of textarea **wym.val()** / **$('.wymeditor').html()**
but ajax sends nothing as parameter.
How can I send the value of textarea with ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be calling the `xhtml()` method on your WYMeditor instance and not on the textarea itself. Assuming you only have one wymeditor, and it's the first on the page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "forms.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        action: 'add', 
        parent: $('input.parent').val(), 
        ntag: $('input.tag').val(), 
        description: $.wymeditors(0).xhtml()
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and pass the test variable to ajax

```
 var test = $('textarea#wymeditor').val();
```

Comment: Be careful with this method. Depending on how you submit the ajax request, your text field isn't guaranteed to have your latest changes from the editor.